# Does C++11 for loop allow new or better optimizations?

Tags: c++, optimization, for-loop, c++11

In C++11 we can now do :

```
void dosomething( std::vector<Thing>& things )
{
    for( Thing& thing : things )
    {
        dofoo( thing );
        wiizzz( thing );
        tadaa( thing );
    }

}
```

I know that the addition and use of lambda is syntactic sugar but it provide interesting optimization opportunities.

What about the for loop? Is it only syntactic sugar or can the compiler optimize some cases that it couldn't or would be too hard to do with handwritten loop?

Comment: Does `for( Thing& thing : things )` in c++0x specify an ordering? or could `thing` appear in any order?

Comment: It just take the iterator from the begin() member of the given container (if it's a class) and iterate until it reach the end() iterator. So it's iterator-dependant, or container-dependant if you want.
In case of a raw array (or array semantic class too?) it will just go from a[0] and end when it get to a[size].

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's just a syntactic sugar since the standard says that it's equivalent to a loop with iterators [ *Edit*: this means it doesn't provide any additional information to the compiler compared to the equivalent for loop — *end edit* ]. You may get a better performance though since it's equivalent to:

```
for(auto iter = con.begin(), end = con.end(); iter != end; ++iter)
{
    auto& ref = *iter;
    // ...
}
```

while most people may write:

```
for(auto iter = con.begin(); iter != con.end(); iter++)
{
    // use *iter directly
    // ...
}
```

which may be slower if the con.end(), iter++ or *iter are not trivial.

[ *Edit*:

> lambda is syntactic sugar

Not really. Unlike for loop it allows the compiler to capture the stack-frame base pointer directly, for variables captured by reference this saves one address indirection per each use, compared to a handcrafted function object. — *end edit* ]

Comment: Are you sure it caches `end()`? This means you can't mutate the collection which is semantically different (for collections that don't invalidate iterators on insertion/deletion e.g. `list`).

Comment: I guess it assumes that the container will no change. If it will, using stl algorithms might be a better way.

Comment: @Motti: the standard says explicitly that it's equivalent to the above code (well, a bit more complicated one because it's phrased in terms of ranges). Anyway if your container doesn't invalidate iterators, then end() is not invalidates. So what's the problem? You can change the container as long as you don't break this code.

Comment: While I don't see any immediate optimization opportunities, the compiler can do whatever it wants under the as-if rule.

Comment: @sellibitze: It does make it much easier for the compiler to prove that `end` doesn't change, and can thus be cached instead of recalculated.  If your loop is complicated, that can be an optimization that would otherwise be missed.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe, but probably not. It does eliminate the possible creating of an index/counter variable that won't be used. That's not *required* for a normal for loop either, but it's a lot more likely to happen just because it's what some people are accustomed to doing.

Realistically, it's unlikely to make any difference even from that though. I, at least, find it hard to imagine a compiler team so sophisticated that they have even the slightest aspiration toward supporting C++0x, that hasn't already handled the relatively trivial point of detecting and eliminating creating and incrementing a loop index that's never used.